# Why positron emission is unlikely to occur for nuclei with an excess of neutrons?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, neutrons, proton-decay

Is it because a neutron decays into a proton and electron rather than a positron. 
Which type of nucleus emits positron and which emits electrons . Is it something to do with beta plus and beta minus decay .

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/249036/why-beta-decay-occurs/249050#249050

Comment: @Farcher: "_Possible duplicate?_ [Why beta+- decay occurs?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/249036)" -- Not really: at least the OP question title implies an inquiry to justify, roughly, "why there is a line/valley of stability in the isotope chart (rather than, say, a line/ridge of instability)". However, admittedly, this request is not (yet) spelled out in the OP question text.

Comment: Follow the logic. *"Positron emission can only occur when a ___ is converted into a ___ inside the nucleus, but in a neutron rich nucleus adding a ___ takes more energy than you get from removing a ___ so the event results in a net energy gain to the nucleus."*

Comment: @dmckee: "_Follow the logic. [...]_" -- Logic allows at least to fill in the blanks you left: "_Positron emission can only occur when a `_$p$_` is converted into a `_$n$_` inside the nucleus_" -- (That's by plain charge conservation; a gimmee.) "_but in a neutron rich nucleus adding a `_$n$_` takes more energy than you get from removing a `_$p$_` so [...]_" -- So the presumed logic holds. But **why** does converting $p$ to $n$ in an already $n$-rich nucleous take more energy than the reverse?? (Why "valley of stability" rather than "ridge of instability"??) And: Does the OP ask this question?

Answer (score 1):

Beta decay occurs, approximately, in nuclei where the [Fermi energy](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/solids/fermi.html) of one species of nucleon is higher than the first unoccupied orbital for the other species.  In these nuclei energy can be liberated by turning one type of nucleon into another --- the new nucleon moves into the available, lower-energy orbital.

By definition, a nucleus with neutron excess has "too many" neutrons already, and it would *cost* energy to turn a proton into another neutron by positron emission.  Such transitions don't happen spontaneously due to conservation of energy.

I have a nice illustration to complement this word salad but I will have to upload it later --- sorry for now.

There are a small number of nuclei, mostly where the number of protons and the number of neutrons are both odd numbers, where the nucleus can release energy by *either* electron or positron decay.
Potassium-40 is one example: most decays are electron decays to calcium-40, but a small fraction are positron decays to argon-40.
This effect some some others in nuclear structure suggest the protons like to pair up with protons, and neutrons like to pair up with neutrons.